# What happened to Google index at 4/12?

Tags: seo, google-index

Two graphs from `Webmaster tools > google index > index status`

[image]

[image]

I working on two websites, they are on different servers, they have nothing in common except I do SEO and everything else for both of them.

Both sites had a negative spike at the number of indexed pages at the same date and they got back to normal at 4/19.

What happened? I didn't find any info about changes in Google algorithm at that date also it is strange both got back to normal at the same time. What could cause these kind of spikes?

Comment: The Google algorithm changes dealing with how they treat mobile sites has been happening this month. Prob adjustments due to that?

Comment: Could have been a phantom update, there was one that happened after mobilegeddon-that-wasn't targeting informational sites i.e. Hubpages.

But since this was a single day, it may have been a test or tweak. According to mozcast.com it was SERPs were relatively stable on April 19th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what FarhadD had to say - this doesn't look like a penalty, just a glitch.

Along with checking the technical issues FarhadD mentioned, another thing to look at is traffic from Google to your website during that same time period (if you use Google Analytics, that is located under Acquisition -> All Traffic -> Source/Medium, then click on google / organic in the table). Did you see any decrease in traffic on one site or another?

If you didn't see a decrease in traffic, that leads more to a glitch with the index status report. If you did see a decrease in traffic from Google, you may want to explore further to figure out what specific pages saw that decrease in traffic...perhaps there was something to those pages (to view this in Google Analytics, after loading that google/organic report under Acquisition, you would add a secondary dimension to the report for landing page and then you can review each to see if you notice any page specific decreases).

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like a dip due to an algorithmic penalty or change. It is more likely a glitch - either in your code, your server settings or in Googlebot crawling your site.

Your first port of call when trouble-shooting this is to double-check that nothing was changes on your site - especially no erroneous robots.txt code, no major directory name / URL changes and nothing else that could have blocked the bots during that period.